# Arrayjob vs array conflict

Tags: tables

I'm using the `arrayjob` package (to have an array data stucture) and I just added the more known `array` to have a vertically centered table (text+pictures).

I get an error and seems it seems the `array` package is executing the `\newarray` command (defined by `arrayjob`).

Usage (to declare a new array named `\Correct`):

```
\usepackage{arrayjob}
\usepackage{array}

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newarray\Correct  % This line triggers the error
\end{document}
```

Error:

> `! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (C): 'c' used.

even though I did not find a `\newarray` command in the `array` documentation.

Anyone has seen this problem? Any ideas can be done to solve it?

(TeXlive in Debian)

Comment: A minimal example of the code producing the error is needed

Comment: Even though the answer is solved, I've edited the code example for posterity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cursory glance at `arrayjob.sty` shows it defines a macro `\array` so it would be incompatible with LaTeX in any case. The same directory has an `arrayjobx.sty` that says

```
% * 05/03/10 - Version 1.04
%              + Change the name of the macro \array to \arrayx
%                to avoid conflict with macros in the amsmath package.
%                Change suggested by Michael Sharpe (msharpe at ucsd.edu)
```

Comment: Well, I've been using arrayjob with LaTeX for a few years without problems. 

`arrayjobx.sty` was not available in my texlive installation but after downloading it and replacing the older package everything works.